# Sports score tracking software?

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator, panel, web-feed

I am looking for a software to track result or live stats of sporting events like Football, Hockey and Cricket ( if possible more sports ).

Reason: Like weather-indicator and typhoon widget on ubuntu work faster than loading weather on webpages, Sports tracking app would be faster to keep tracking sports live scores and save precious bandwidth while one works on his excel sheet or other work.

On other platforms there are apps available like [example 1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.espn.fc), [example 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freerange360.mpp.GOAL)
which show results in notification. So in my case if I am working on editing my college assignment on Libre Office it would be great if live cricket scores or football scores are running in a widget or indicator.

Please tell me such software as I am huge fan of sporting events or any concept i can use to merge HTML score script from websites (score service provider) to unity panel.

Update: I googled and found this *[cricket-score-indicator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cricket_score_indicator/)* but is specifically for cricket only, what about football - BPL, UEFA are must follow to me. But it didn't work for me. Installed but not available in applications tab. Can someone check it for me, so that atleast i can have cricket feeds.

Comment: Does [Software Manager 2015](http://store.steampowered.com/app/295270) fit?  Do these people have RSS feeds available?

Comment: @earthmeLon the software you mentioned is a game not a score tracker. Thanks for looking into matter but this doesn't qualify

Comment: Someone said it made such an indicator but it didn't post the code: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=196499&page=15 Maybe if you remind him...

Comment: Sorry, not an answer. Don't have the "reputation" for comment. I'm the author of `cricket-score-indicator`.
I may be able to write `football-score-indicator` if someone can point me to a publicly accessible API for retrieving the latest scores.

Comment: @rawcoder thjs your cricket score indicator is great. can you please use espn or some sport/news site which provides api for retreiving scores, it would be very helpful for football(talking about the one which Messi plays not american football) enthusiasts

Answer (score 2):

### [livescore-cli](https://github.com/codeezer/livescore-cli)

It is a small commandline program to watch scores, tables and fixtures of football(soccer) from the commandline. It requires the python interpreter(2). It uses the data from the website livescore.com and some other websites. It is essentially built for the busy people that are passionate about football.

#### Features :

- Real Time Livescore
- Match Time in Local Time
- League Table
- Top Scorers List
- News Feed

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use an RSS indicator programme plugged to the Panel. A few options:

- [Feed Indicator](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator) - possibly the most feature rich.
- [Yarssr](http://yarssr.sourceforge.net/) - available from the Software Centre.
- [Tickr](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/tickr/) - available from the Software Centre.

Then you just need to add a feed from a sports ticker website such as the one from the [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/live-scores).

Comment: well i use sports feed using thunderbird feed subscription. It is not very efficient way as one has to read scores by opening a heading which is more like `reading an article` rather than `having a quick glance` over the scores. Feed indicator appears promising for placing itself in panel but still one has to go through whole feed instead of easily reading `dynamically changing score bar`. Anyways +1 for this suggestion which i was already using. I will still follow this question for a better concept

Comment: With these programmes you will get a notification every time a new score is published, just like Rhythmbox notifies you it starts playing a new track.